# What's your trick to document (in the UI?) variables overridden in settings.php?

Tags: configuration

If you define variable overrides in `settings.php`, there is no visible change to the admin UI. It's easy when overtired (or just inexperienced) to overlook this when changing some config through the UI, and getting an unexpected result.

Have people come up with a trick to document `settings.php` overrides right in the related admin form? I guess I could write a `form_alter` every time I define a settings.php override, but is there an alternative clever that devs are using? (I'm using D7, BTW.)

Comment: For reference, this may eventually be fixed: https://www.drupal.org/node/2408549

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a hook_help that displays a message on the page where you would set the variable. Would still need to do it manually per variable though.

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Patrick comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247343/whats-your-trick-to-document-in-the-ui-variables-overridden-in-settings-php#comment302984_247343), you can apply the patch from [#2408549 Drupal issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2408549) which will display a message on the top if there are overridden values.

> Each configuration form knows about the configuration keys edited and centralizes an accessor (`$this->config()`) to access them. Thanks to this, we can track if there were any configuration details loaded that may have overrides applied (by loading the editable version as well and comparing the data). That way, we can detect if there are overridden values at least under the same conditions as the admin form was displayed (eg. *static global overrides*). Using that information, we can display a message on top of the form if there is overridden configuration and editing is pointless.

However the patch is for Drupal 8, so either you need upgrade your site to 8.5.x or wait to be ported to Drupal 7.